# Place the content in a block with shadow frame

Tags: beamer, listings, block

I am using latex beamer and trying to put the content of the listing in a block with white background and just with a shadow of the frame as the one of google (madrid weather).

I tried with `\begin{block}{xyz} \end{block}` but it produces another block as what I really want.

I want a block as this one:

[image]

current state:

[image]

**code:**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\JSONnumbervaluestyle{\color{red}}
\newcommand\JSONstringvaluestyle{\color{red}}

% switch used as state variable
\newif\ifcolonfoundonthisline

\makeatletter

\lstdefinestyle{json}
{
  showstringspaces    = false,
  alsoletter          = 0123456789.,
  morestring          = [s]{"}{"},
  stringstyle         = \ifcolonfoundonthisline\JSONstringvaluestyle\fi,
  MoreSelectCharTable =%
    \lst@DefSaveDef{`:}\colon@json{\processColon@json},
  basicstyle          = \ttfamily\small,
  keywordstyle        = \ttfamily\bfseries,
}

% flip the switch if a colon is found in Pmode
\newcommand\processColon@json{%
  \colon@json%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \global\colonfoundonthislinetrue%
  \fi
}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}{%
  \ifcolonfoundonthisline%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
      \def\lst@thestyle{\JSONnumbervaluestyle}%
    \fi
  \fi
  %override by keyword style if a keyword is detected!
  \lsthk@DetectKeywords% 
}

% reset the switch at the end of line
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}%
  {\global\colonfoundonthislinefalse}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}



\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{JSON array of the timetable sheets}

JSON array of the parsed timetable sheets:
\bigbreak


\begin{lstlisting}[style=json]

  [{"stops": [{
           "arrival_time": {
                  "mon-fri": [ "04:31", "04:43"],
                  "sat":     ["05:32", "06:32"],                                     
                  "sun":     ["05:32", "06:32"]
                           },   
           "stop_name": "XYZ",
           "stop_lat": "90.874136",
           "stop_long": "19.665553"
             }]
  }]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `tcolorbox` package.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the code in a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure} 
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand\JSONnumbervaluestyle{\color{red}}
\newcommand\JSONstringvaluestyle{\color{red}}

% switch used as state variable
\newif\ifcolonfoundonthisline

\makeatletter

\lstdefinestyle{json}
{
  showstringspaces    = false,
  alsoletter          = 0123456789.,
  morestring          = [s]{"}{"},
  stringstyle         = \ifcolonfoundonthisline\JSONstringvaluestyle\fi,
  MoreSelectCharTable =%
    \lst@DefSaveDef{`:}\colon@json{\processColon@json},
  basicstyle          = \ttfamily\small,
  keywordstyle        = \ttfamily\bfseries,
}

% flip the switch if a colon is found in Pmode
\newcommand\processColon@json{%
  \colon@json%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \global\colonfoundonthislinetrue%
  \fi
}

\lst@AddToHook{Output}{%
  \ifcolonfoundonthisline%
    \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
      \def\lst@thestyle{\JSONnumbervaluestyle}%
    \fi
  \fi
  %override by keyword style if a keyword is detected!
  \lsthk@DetectKeywords% 
}

% reset the switch at the end of line
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}%
  {\global\colonfoundonthislinefalse}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{JSON array of the timetable sheets}

JSON array of the parsed timetable sheets:
\bigbreak
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=white,colframe=white,sharpish corners,fuzzy halo=0.5mm with lightgray]
\begin{lstlisting}[style=json]
[{"stops": [{
    "arrival_time": {
      "mon-fri": [ "04:31", "04:43"],
    "sat":     ["05:32", 06:32"],                                     
    "sun":     ["05:32", "06:32"]
  },   
    "stop_name": "XYZ",
  "stop_lat": "90.874136",
  "stop_long": "19.665553"
  }]
}]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]